# Why System.StackOverflowException appear only on some machines?

Tags: c#, events, recursion

Unintentionally I made some loop inside code which call event handler itself all the time. I haven't experienced any problems on my PC (Win7 64) and on work mate when he run it on XP neither. But on third PC also with Win7 64 the application crashes.

I go through debugger on my PC and colleague's PC and even the behavior inside debugger was different.

I can say, that my PC somehow manage this problem and go outside at last (I don't know why), and on second PC it just stuck inside infinite loop. What can be the reason? Long story short - code below used to work on two PCs, and doesn't work on another ones - why?

```
private void comboBoxBasicTabBasicProfile_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _profilesContainer.SetCurrentBasicConfig((BasicConfigSTD32)comboBoxBasicTabBasicConfig.SelectedItem);
    loadBasicConfigsToGUI();
}

private void loadBasicConfigsToGUI()
{
    var currentConfig = _profilesContainer.GetCurrentBasicConfig();
    comboBoxStatusTabBasicConfig.Items.Refresh();
    comboBoxBasicTabBasicConfig.Items.Refresh();

    comboBoxStatusTabBasicConfig.ItemsSource = _profilesContainer.BasicConfigList;
    comboBoxStatusTabBasicConfig.SelectedItem = currentConfig;
    comboBoxBasicTabBasicConfig.ItemsSource = _profilesContainer.BasicConfigList;
    comboBoxBasicTabBasicConfig.SelectedItem = currentConfig;
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but Refreshing the CollectionView might trigger a SelectionChanged, which cause the view to refresh again. But why it works on one pc and not on another is very difficult to answer like that. Might be a different stack size, might be a matter of running out of memory.

Comment: You're probably triggering the `SelectionChanged` event in `loadBasicConfigsToGUI` when you change the `SelectedItem`. The different behavior on different computers could be caused by the `SelectedItem` for some reason already being the same as what it gets set to in some, but not all, cases. Why are you doing all that stuff every time the selection is changed?

Comment: If you really need to do all this stuff, then remove the SelectionChanged event on start of comboBoxBasicTabBasicProfile_SelectionChanged and add it again at the end

Comment: Uwe - yes it was first what I did to proof that is the problem - it helped, but I have to change it anyway.
MagnusGrindalBakken - As I wrote, I shouldn't do that, but I did by mistake. The problem is that I couldn't find it until I run application on different PC.
The question still is, what can be reason of different behaviors.